# Backbonejs Router navigate function does not trigger router function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, backbone-routing

My route function is not triggered when I call `app.navigate("/search#?q="+q, {trigger: true});`.

The route are defined well because if I refresh the page after the navigate() call, the route function is correctly triggered.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I never used # in the navigate, does it is the issue? try this: app.navigate("/search?q="+q, {trigger: true});

Answer (score 0):

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

that might help.